# Separate triggers for different branches in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working with a Multi-Branch Jenkins build, of which I want the develop branch to build periodically every two weeks and leave the master branch manual.

Our pipelines are pipelines as code, so I cannot set the config for the desired branches.

I'd like to build our develop branch once every 2 weeks on a sunday, so far I have found some different things.

Right now I've come to this schedule:

```
triggers {
    cron('00 12 /2 7')
}
```

But I do not know how to make it branch specific.
I'm trying this right now to see if it works, should trigger a develop build every 5 mins or break.

```
    triggers {
        when (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop') {
            cron('H/5 * * * *')
        }
    }
```

when is not allowed in the triggers block.

I have found a 'solution' on the Jenkins jira which is this:

```
String cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "develop" ? "00 12 /2 7" : ""

pipeline {
    agent none
    triggers { cron(cron_string) }
    stages {
    // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention that you found a 'solution'. Does that code snippet work as you expect? Does that mean this question is resolved?

Comment: The last snippet is a work around that works as expected, this issue is resolved.

Comment: @ralphcom make your solution a self-answer and accept it. you get fake internet points, and everyone else can tell what the actual fix is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found a 'solution' on the Jenkins jira which is this:

```
String cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "develop" ? "00 12 /2 7" : ""

pipeline {
    agent none
    triggers { cron(cron_string) }
    stages {
    // do something
    }
}
```